# Search backbonejs collections

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone js collection with multiple models:

```
Model 1:
tag: 1
id : 2
name: test

Model 2:
tag: 3
id: 3
name: test3
```

How do I search the collection for a particular model by tag attribute? 
Like if I want to find the model with tag=2 ... How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`findWhere`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere):

Returns only the first model in the collection that matches the passed attributes.

```
collection.findWhere({tag: 2})
```